# Custom 'static' template tag in Django

Tags: python, django, static

everyone!
I need to make some specific changes for static tag. It's result of hours of my work, but I got not what I needed. Following code works properly only if I remove "django.contrib.staticfiles" from INSTALLED_APPS. But it's not right way, because I turn off whole functionality of this app.
Please, help me solve this issue. How can I specific a priority of "staticfiles".

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    # 'django.contrib.staticfiles',        
)
```

myapp/templatetags/staticfiles.py:

```
import re
from django import template
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import StaticFilesNode
from myapp.settings.local import STATIC_VERSION


class CustomStaticFilesNode(StaticFilesNode):

    @classmethod
    def handle_token(cls, parser, token):
        path = versioning_js_and_css(
            token.split_contents()[1],
            get_actual_version()
        )
        node_obj = super().handle_token(parser, token)
        node_obj.path = parser.compile_filter(path)
        return node_obj


def get_actual_version():
    return STATIC_VERSION


def versioning_js_and_css(path, version, tpl="'{path}?v={version}'"):
    try:
        cleaned_path = re.search("\'(.*?)\'", path).group(1)
        if cleaned_path.endswith('.css') or cleaned_path.endswith('.js'):
            path = tpl.format(path=cleaned_path, version=version)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    return path


def do_static_custom(parser, token):
    return CustomStaticFilesNode.handle_token(parser, token)

register = template.Library()
register.tag('static', do_static_custom)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are not allowed to have two apps with the same name (Django's `staticfiles` app and your `staticfiles` app). You can only have one. I would rename your `staticfiles` app to something else, and I would rename your `static` tag to something else as well.

Comment: I just renamed `staticfiles.py` to `custom_staticfiles.py` and added `load custom_staticfiles` to the base template. Now it works together with the django staticfiles app!
But now I got the next issue, but I think it has nothing to do with the starting problem. I get "manifest.js%3Fv%3D0.0.1" instead of "manifest.js?v=0.0.1". I guess it's the Jade issue, which I using with this project. 
Thank you, for the quick help @grantmcconnaughey !